Open Shell command from Excel-VBA with variant Unicode-folder
I would like to open the Explorer from Excel-VBA, in a folder that the user chooses and the folder is not in English. I saved the folder name in the ChrW code.
When I use the following code the Explorer opens in the correct folder:
Sub Show_Folder()
    Shell "Explorer.exe c:\" & ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1488), vbNormalFocus
End Sub

but when I use a variant, the Explorer opens in its default position:
Sub Show_Folder()
    Dim FolderCode As String
    FolderCode = "ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1488)"
    Shell "Explorer.exe c:\" & FolderCode, vbNormalFocus
End Sub

I tried to play with FolderCode adding "&" and " & " to its start with no luck...
What am I missing?

The reason behind it is that there is no folder named ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1488). Remove the quotes i.e. use FolderCode = ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1488) to explore folder אמא. You could consider an alternative: ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "C:\" & FolderCode with a difference that it doesn't open a new window if one is already open.

Sub ShowFolder2()
  Dim FolderCode  As String
FolderCode = ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1488)
Shell "Explorer.exe C:\" & FolderCode & ", vbNormalFocus"

End Sub

Edit
Although inefficient, if, for the reasons you stated in your comment, FolderCode contains the actual string "ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1488)", you could replace ChrW with Unichar to create an Excel formula, and then apply the Evaluate function.
It would seem more efficient for your drop-down to contain the actual letters or even the corresponding Excel function UNICHAR.
Option Explicit

Sub ShowFolder2()
  Dim FolderCode  As String

FolderCode = "ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1488)"
FolderCode = Evaluate(Replace(FolderCode, "ChrW", "UNICHAR"))

Shell "Explorer.exe C:\" & FolderCode & ", vbNormalFocus"

End Sub


Thanks you @Black cat , @VBasic2008 and @Ron Rosenfeld , This works great!
What do I do if the text ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1488) inside FolderCode comes as a variant, how do I make it workable?
I tried using Evaluate(FolderCode) and expression.Evaluate(FolderCode) but with no success.

@Duvdi The code I provided will still work if FolderCode is a variant. More efficient as String, though. Why would you want it to be a variant?

what I meant is that this value is changed according to the user selection. Let's say it is received in A1 cell. So when I bring it by using FolderCode = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value the Shell request doesn't open it correctly.

@Duvdi  What, exactly, is in A1? If A1 contains the actual string אמא it works ok with FolderCode = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"). If you are going to have them type out the unicodes, then have them create the string on the worksheet with the worksheet functions, not the VBA functions: =UNICHAR(1488) & UNICHAR(1502) & UNICHAR(1488)

The A1 cell gets the ChrW string following a selection done by the user in a different cell. I believe the problem is that FolderCode understands the string as "ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1488)" instead of ChrW(1488) & ChrW(1502) & ChrW(1488). This is the reason I'm looking for an expression like Evaluate() to solve it...

@Duvdi That seems pretty inefficient, but see my Edit for a workaround.
